# How to sum all y values of all x arrays 2d array into a 1d array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to store all values of a x*y int array into an x length array, but no matter how I do it I end up with various runtime errors. Here is my current code:

```
    for(int x=0; x < size.length; x++){

        for(int y=0; y < orders; y++){

            totalGears[x] += gears[x][y];
        }
    }
```

The purpose of the program is to calculate the number of different sized gears ordered, where x specifies the order, and y specifies the number of unique gears, for example in array gears[][] x would be 10 if 10 orders are entered, and y would be 3 if there are 3 sizes of gears. So if order 0 is for 3 large gears, 4 medium gears and 6 small gears, the contents of gears[0][3] is 6.

Except when I run the program, everything is fine until I hit this part when this runs and I get the following:

Large - [I@33909752
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I've tried rearranging everything I can think of. This type of nested for loop works multiple times throughout the program, so I can't figure out why it throws an error here. All the arrays are Int arrays.

EDIT: Resolved - Changing 
            totalGears[x] += gears[x][y]
to
            totalGears[x] = totalGears[x] + gears[x][y]

solved the issue, but I have no clue why

Comment: paper and pencil this one. I suspect is one of those `<=` errors

Comment: Can we see the declarations of totalGears and gears?

Comment: what is `size.length`? obviously it's an `array` of some sort but is it the right size? also what is `orders`

Comment: size.length is the length of the size array. size is a string array that contains the descriptions of each size. Right now its contents are {"large","medium","small"}. It is passed to this method from main.

orders is the number of entered orders, i.e. if I enter 10 orders of various quantities of gears, it would be an int with value of 10.

Comment: int[]totalGears = new int[size.length];

Comment: @coffee what is a <= error? If size.length = 3 and orders = 10, I would want the first loop to run 3 times and the inside loop to run 10 times every time, right? So < would be right since I declare x and y as 0, no?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not exceeding the bounds of `gears` as well as `gears[x]`:

```
int[]totalGears = new int[size.length];
for(int x=0; x < Math.min(size.length,gears.length); x++){
  for(int y=0; y < Math.min(gears[x].length,shipments); y++){
    totalGears[x] += gears[x][y];
  }
}
```

Comment: So I fixed that, but it still throws the same error. I was doing it backwards, what I want to sum up is all the y values of an [x][y] array

Comment: for(int x=0; x < size.length; x++){
   
   for(int y=0; y < orders; y++){
    
    totalGears[x] += gears[x][y];
   }

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try

Comment: Jesus, so I changed the totalGears[x] += gears[x][y] to totalGears[x] = totalGears[x] + gears[x][y] and now it works fine :/ 

Why on earth would += cause an error here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Java 8 you can simplify your solution a lot:

```
int[] totalGears = IntStream.range(0, gears.length)
    .mapToInt(i -> Arrays.stream(gears[i]).sum()).toArray();
```

That safely copes with uneven and empty arrays and avoid some pretty error prone iterations.